# How can I flatten lists without splitting strings?

Tags: python

I'd like to flatten lists that may contain other lists *without* breaking strings apart. For example:

```
In [39]: list( itertools.chain(*["cat", ["dog","bird"]]) )
Out[39]: ['c', 'a', 't', 'dog', 'bird']
```

and I would like

```
['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
```

Comment: The problem is not well specified. Is the input a mixture of lists and strings? If so, why not just wrap the strings in one-element lists? Or do we need to flatten a possibly deeply nested structure? What does it mean to say "may contain other lists"? Usually, "may" entails "might not". But if the list **doesn't** contain any other lists, then what flattening is there to do?

Comment: On second thought, this should probably be a duplicate of [flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists).

Comment: On *third* thought, the problem does seem to come up fairly often, with this very specific setup (mixed strings and lists, only one level of flattening is desired). Possibly this should be a separate question, and some dupes of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists belong here instead.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Solution:

```
def flatten(foo):
    for x in foo:
        if hasattr(x, '__iter__') and not isinstance(x, str):
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x
```

---

#### Old version for Python 2.x:

```
def flatten(foo):
    for x in foo:
        if hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x
```

(In Python 2.x, strings conveniently didn't actually have an `__iter__` attribute, unlike pretty much every other iterable object in Python. Note however that they do in Python 3, so the above code will only work in Python 2.x.)

Comment: Only the Python 3 version uses `isinstance()` and there's no `basestring` class in Python 3 since all strings are Unicode.

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell: `hasattr(u'foo', '__iter__') == False` in Python 2.x, and Python 3 doesn't have a `basestring`, all it has is `str` (which is unicode) and `bytes`.

Comment: It looks like the Python 3 version would work in Python 2 also, even if it's a little bit redundant.

Answer (score 9):

A slight modification of orip's answer that avoids creating an intermediate list:

```
import itertools
items = ['cat',['dog','bird']]
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x,1) if isinstance(x,str) else x for x in items)
```

Answer (score 2):

a brute force way would be to wrap the string in its own list, then use `itertools.chain`

```
>>> l = ["cat", ["dog","bird"]]
>>> l2 = [([x] if isinstance(x,str) else x) for x in l]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*l2))
['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def squash(L):
    if L==[]:
        return []
    elif type(L[0]) == type(""):
        M = squash(L[1:])
        M.insert(0, L[0])
        return M
    elif type(L[0]) == type([]):
        M = squash(L[0])
        M.append(squash(L[1:]))
        return M

def flatten(L):
    return [i for i in squash(L) if i!= []]

>> flatten(["cat", ["dog","bird"]])
['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner approach:

```
[item for sublist in [[item] if type(item) is not list else item for item in list1] for item in sublist]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `reduce` function from the `functools` library you can do it like this:

```
import functools
items = ['cat',['dog','bird']]
print(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: [a] + b, items))
```

Comment: Does not work if the first element of `items` is a list: `functools.reduce(lambda a, b: [a] + b,  [["dog", "bird"], "cat"])` gives `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Answer (score 1):

a lambda function approach that works for more than two levels of hierarchy

```
>>> items = ['cat',['dog','bird',['fish']]] 
>>> flatten = lambda y: [k for j in ([i] if not isinstance(i,list) else flatten(i) for i in y) for k in j]
>>> flatten(items)
['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'fish']
```

Comment: Just want to clarify that while this code will work, this is a violation of PEP-8 standards, which will state that you should not assign a lambda expression to a variable, and instead use a full function definition instead.