# Flatten a list of strings and lists of strings and lists in Python

Tags: python, list

Similar questions have been asked before, but the solutions to those don't work for my use case (e.g., [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) and [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python). I have is a list of strings and lists, where embedded list can also contain strings and lists. I want to turn this into a simple list of strings without splitting strings into list of characters.

```
import itertools

list_of_menuitems = ['image10', ['image00', 'image01'], ['image02', ['image03', 'image04']]]
chain = itertools.chain(*list_of_menuitems)
```

Resulting list:

```
['i', 'm', 'a', 'g', 'e', '1', '0', 'image00', 'image01', 'image02', ['image03', 'image04']]
```

Expected result:

```
['image10', 'image00', 'image01', 'image02', 'image03', 'image04']
```

What's the best (Pythonic) way to do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176742/python-3-replacement-for-deprecated-compiler-ast-flatten-function

Comment: I agree that it's an almost-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286541/how-can-i-flatten-lists-without-splitting-strings. The one dimension here that is missing from that question (which I hadn't found before asking my question) is the issue of arbitrary levels of nesting. However, the solution posted there (and at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176742/python-3-replacement-for-deprecated-compiler-ast-flatten-function) handles this issue quite nicely, at least for the case I provided.

Comment: OP: use `basestring` instead of `str` so that you don't split `unicode`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The oft-repeated [`flatten`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) function can be applied to this circumstance with a simple modification.

```
from collections import Iterable
def flatten(coll):
    for i in coll:
            if isinstance(i, Iterable) and not isinstance(i, basestring):
                for subc in flatten(i):
                    yield subc
            else:
                yield i
```

`basestring` will make sure that both `str` and `unicode` objects are not split.

There are also versions which count on `i` not having the `__iter__` attribute. I don't know about all that, because I think that `str` now has that attribute. But, it's worth mentioning.

(Please upvote the linked answer.)

Comment: I do suspect it would have been better to just link to that answer, that way it would serve as direction, and wouldn't introduce duplication.

Answer (score 12):

Using recursion.

```
def flatten(A):
    rt = []
    for i in A:
        if isinstance(i,list): rt.extend(flatten(i))
        else: rt.append(i)
    return rt
```

Test:

```
>>> list_of_menuitems = ['image10', ['image00', 'image01'], ['image02', ['image0
3', 'image04']]]
>>> flattern(list_of_menuitems)
['image10', 'image00', 'image01', 'image02', 'image03', 'image04']
```

Answer (score 9):

The following works for strings (and would be easily adapted to other types):

```
def flatten_to_strings(listOfLists):
    """Flatten a list of (lists of (lists of strings)) for any level 
    of nesting"""
    result = []

    for i in listOfLists:
        # Only append if i is a basestring (superclass of string)
        if isinstance(i, basestring):
            result.append(i)
        # Otherwise call this function recursively
        else:
            result.extend(flatten_to_strings(i))
    return result

flatten_to_strings(list_of_menuitems)
Out[2]: ['image10', 'image00', 'image01', 'image02', 'image03', 'image04']
```

Comment: This has some redundancy - isinstance takes account of inheritance, and you could switch the none test to the recursive branch

Comment: @marcin Thanks for your comment. I tweaked my code to address these points.

Comment: I like how straightforward this one is. In python 3.2 I just had to replace basestring with str and it works EXACTLY as I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

In one specialized case when none of the list items contains one of the following delimiters `[]'`, you can use the following hack. I have not profiled it, but it looks obvious that, this would have a better performance than the obvious and cleaner recursive solution.

```
>>> str(list_of_menuitems).translate(None,"[]'").split(',')
['image10', ' image00', ' image01', ' image02', ' image03', ' image04']
```

I agree, this is a dirty hack, but does the JOB, without much effort.

Comment: I would downvote this, except that you explained clearly its drawbacks. So it's a good reference I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic recursive flatten which can be used to work with any combination of types which should or should not be flattened:

```
import collections
def generic_flatten(seq, flatten_types=(tuple,list,set),atom_types=(basestring,dict),fixtype=True):
    newseq = []
    for item in seq:
        if (not isinstance(collections.Iterable)) or any(isinstance(i,t) for t in atom_types):
           newseq.append(item)
        elif any(isinstance(i,t) for t in flatten_types): # set flatten_types to (object,) or (collections.Iterable,) to disable check
           newseq.extend(generic_flatten(item, flatten_types, atom_types,fixtype)
    if fixtype and type(newseq) is not type(seq):
       newseq = type(seq)(newseq)
    return newseq
```

`yield` and `chain` could be used to create a generic iterator-based version.