# Nested Lists- Python

Tags: python, list, nested

I need to write the body of a Python method that does the following:

1)takes a list, where list[0] is a string and list[1] is either a list which looks the same or None

2)print every string of the list

I have to use the while loop and not use list comprehension or flatten.

```
def pick_cherries_iter(field):
    """"e.g.
    >>> cherry_field = ['cherry1', ['cherry2', ['cherry3', ['cherry4', ['Yay!!!', None]]]]]
    >>> pick_cherries_iter(cherry_field)
    cherry1
    cherry2
    cherry3
    cherry4
    Yay!!!"""

    _______________________
    _______________________
    _______________________
    _______________________
    while _________________:
        _______________________
        _______________________
        _______________________
```

I know that for the example above I can print cheery1 if I print cherry_field[0] or cherry1 for cherry_field[1][0] or cherry2 for cherry_filed[1][1][0] etc, however I am not sure how to go through these elements using the while loop.

Comment: Is this an assignment that you have been given?

Comment: Yes, it is an assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten a list of strings and lists of strings and lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864466/flatten-a-list-of-strings-and-lists-of-strings-and-lists-in-python)

Comment: It is not, I should not use flatten.

Comment: is there a guarantee in the assignment that each list is at most 2 elements long?

Comment: @KenHBS you should link to a non-duplicate thread.

Comment: Yes its a guarantee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you. Please check it.

**Using While Loop:**

```
def pick_cherry(field):
    """"e.g.
    >>> cherry_field = ['cherry1', ['cherry2', ['cherry3', ['cherry4', ['Yay!!!',None]]]]]
    >>> pick_cherry(cherry_field)
    cherry1
    cherry2
    cherry3
    cherry4
    Yay!!!"""

    while field[1] != None:
        temp = field[0]
        print temp
        field = field[1]
    print field[0]
```

**Using Flatten(and Recursion):**

```
flatten_field = []

def pick_cherry(field):
    if field[1] != None:
        flatten_field.append(field[0])
        pick_cherry(field[1])
    else:
        flatten_field.append(field[0])

def flatten_func(field):
    """"e.g.
    >>> cherry_field = ['cherry1', ['cherry2', ['cherry3', ['cherry4', ['Yay!!!',None]]]]]
    >>> flatten_func(cherry_field)
    cherry1
    cherry2
    cherry3
    cherry4
    Yay!!!"""

    pick_cherry(field)

    for item in flatten_field:
        print item
```

Comment: If I had to use flatten (and recursion), how could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this recursively because you have no way of knowing if an element is a list or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -E

cherry_field = ['cherry1', ['cherry2', ['cherry3', ['cherry4', ['Yay!!!', None]]]]]
def print_list(field):
    i = 0
    list_length = len(field)
    while i < list_length:
     if field[i] is not None and type(field[i]) is not list:
        print(field[i])
     else:
        if field[i] is not None:
           print_list(field[i])
     i += 1
     if i < list_length and type(field[i]) is list:
        print_list(field[i])
        i += 1


def pick_cherries(field):
    if type(field) is list:
       print_list(field)

pick_cherries(cherry_field)
```

Comment: Does your answer include list comprehension?

Comment: I just tested on a variety of nested lists, made a couple minor changes, and it seems to work on everything so far.  That's the advantage of recursion.

Comment: For example, it can also do this list:  cherry_field = ['cherry1', ['cherry2', ['cherry3', ['cherry4', ['Yay!!!', None]]]],'cherry5']

Comment: Your answer using recursion is just fine, my question is whether you are using list coprehension or not.

Comment: Umm, no.  Referring back to the OP's question, I do not see that requirement.