# Join list of lists and strings into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm having an issue to join lists.

```
list = ['a','b',['c','d'],['e']]
```

I need this:

```
list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Comment: This is a different question than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: Dupe: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864466/flatten-a-list-of-strings-and-lists-of-strings-and-lists-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864466/flatten-a-list-of-strings-and-lists-of-strings-and-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `list` as a variable name (it would even break my code example):

```
import itertools as it
items = ['a','b',['c','d'],['e']]

# in a single line:

flat = list(it.chain.from_iterable([item if isinstance(item, list) else [item] for item in items])) 

# or in several lines:
flat = []
for item in items:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        flat.extend(item)
    else:
        flat.append(item)
```

Comment: youre right - doesnt hanle mix of strings and lists. thanks

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpfull .Been all night trying to figure this out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864466/flatten-a-list-of-strings-and-lists-of-strings-and-lists-in-python  is a dupe though.