# How to delete all none elements from a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I want to get the only Non-None element from this list:

```
L = [None, [None,None], [None, <__main__.Car object at 0x02A11550>], [None, None, None], None]
```

I've tried

```
L = [x for x in L if x is not None]
```

But the result is

```
[[None, None], [None, <__main__.Car object at 0x02A11550>], [None, None, None]]
```

Deleting only the None that are not inside of any list. 
Is there any way to clean the whole list? so the output is

```
<__main__.Car object at 0x02A11550>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def flatten(lst):
    for element in lst:
        if hasattr(element,"__iter__"):
            yield from flatten(element)
        elif not element is None:
            yield element

new_list = flatten(L)
```

I'll break this down for you, first starting with generators. The `yield` keyword is sister to `return`, but with much different functionality. Both are used to bring values out of a function into its calling scope, but `yield` allows you to jump back into the function afterwards! As an example, below is a generator that accepts a list full of numbers and produces the square for each number in the list.

```
def example_generator(number_list):
    for number in number_list:
        yield number**2

>>> gen = example_generator([1,2,3])
>>> type(gen)
<class 'generator'>
>>> next(gen) # next() is used to get the next value from an iterator
1
>>> next(gen)
4
>>> next(gen)
9
>>> next(gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    next(gen)
StopIteration
```

Generators are one-time use, however. As you can see, after I reached the end of the generator, it threw an exception `StopIteration`. If I built it again and ran through it with a loop, then tried to run through it AGAIN...

```
>>> gen = example_generator([1,2,3]) # remember this is a new generator, we JUST made it
>>> for item in gen:
...     print(item)
1
4
9
>>> for item in gen:
...     print(item)
>>>
```

It doesn't do anything the second time. The generator is exhausted. That's the downside -- the upside is that it's generally much faster and more memory-efficient to use generators instead of lists.

`yield` also allows you to use another keyword: `from`. That's what I did there in case of a nested list (`hasattr(element,"__iter__")` just means that the element has an attribute `.__iter__`, which means it can be iterated upon using something like a `for` loop). You give `yield from` another generator, and it yields each element from THAT generator in turn. For example:

```
def flatten_lite(lst):
    for element in lst:
        if type(element) is list: # more readable, IMO
            yield from flatten_lite(element)
        else:
            yield element

a = flatten_lite([1,2,3,[4,5,6,[7],8],9])
```

Here's what it does in turn:

```
for element in [1,2,3,[4,5,6,[7],8],9]:
    # element == 1
    if element is of type list: # it's not, skip this
    else: yield element # which is 1
    :: NEXT ITERATION ::
    # element == 2, same as before
    :: NEXT ITERATION ::
    # element == 3, same as before
    :: NEXT ITERATION ::
    # element == [4,5,6,[7],8]
    if element is of type list: # it is!!
        yield from flatten_lite([4,5,6,[7],8])
        :: STOP EXECUTION UNTIL WE GET A VALUE FROM THAT NEW GENERATOR ::
>>> NEW GENERATOR
for element in [4,5,6,[7],8]:
    # element is 4
    yield 4
        :: THE OUTER GENERATOR YIELDS 4 ::
    :: NEXT ITERATION ::
    # element is 5
    yield 5
        :: THE OUTER GENERATOR YIELDS 4 ::
    :: NEXT ITERATION ::
    # element is 6
    yield 6
        :: THE OUTER GENERATOR YIELDS 4 ::
    :: NEXT ITERATION ::
    # element is [7]
    if element is of type list # [7] is a list!
        yield from flatten_lite([7])
            :: STOP EXECUTION UNTIL WE GET A VALUE FROM THAT NEW GENERATOR ::
            # etc etc
```

So basically the code above says (in pseudocode):

```
flatten is a function that accepts parameter: lst
    for each element in lst:
        if element can be iterated on:
            yield every element in turn from the generator created
              by this function called on the element instead of the
              main list
        if it's not, and isn't None:
            yield element
```

When you call it, it builds a generator that can be iterated upon. To make it into a formal list, you'll have to do `list(flatten(L))`, but in most cases you don't need that.

Is that any clearer?

Comment: You need to be careful witht his. A `str` instance has an `__iter__` method (in Python 3), but you don't want to try recursively flattening it.

Comment: The code works perfectly, but I'm new to python and i don't really understand how it does it, is there any way to make the same thing by using comprehension lists or recursive functions?

Comment: @user3440055 yeah gimme a few and I'll help out.

Comment: @Blckknght a great point! I could maybe use `isinstance(element,list)` but would miss out on TONS of iterables I want to flatten. Conversely I feel like `if hasattr(element,"__iter__") and not isinstance(element,str)` includes other string-like objects that can be iterated upon but are not sequences. Is there a superclass for all sequences that should be "flatten-able?"

Comment: @Dagont I explained my code in exhaustive detail, but let me know if there's something I missed!

Comment: `yield from iterable` [only works in Python 3.3 and above](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380). See [PEP-380](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly more modular approach:

```
def flatten(l):
    """ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python/2158532#2158532 """
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

filter(None,flatten(L)) #wrap with `list` in python 3.x
```

A generic `flatten` function is something you should keep in your toolbox, since (so far) it's not something you can find in the standard library, and it comes up occasionally.

Comment: If the nested list can contain strings, this will be worse than adsmith's answer, since it will infinitely recurse in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @Blckknght you're right, I tried to do this one from memory.  The above is the one I have sitting on my HD.  I'm sure I've pulled it from another stackoverflow answer, I'll attribute it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, how about:

```
from itertools import chain, ifilterfalse
result = list(ifilterfalse(lambda x: x is None, chain(*[x for x in L if x is not None])))
```

This will return a `list` with only the `Car` element present. It will generalize to return a `list` with any non-`None` element.

In Python 3.x I think you swap `ifilterfalse` for `filterfalse` and it works the same.

`chain()` is designed to flatten a `list` of `list`s for iteration. `ifilterfalse` can work directly on the `chain` returned. `ifilterfalse` gets rid of elements that match the predicate specified by the `lambda` function.

Note that if you have strings in `L`, `chain()` will essentially break the strings up into individual elements. If that is a problem for you, see this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286541/how-can-i-flatten-lists-without-splitting-strings).

Another implementation which avoids the problem of non-iterables at the base level:

```
result = list(ifilterfalse(lambda x: x is None, chain(*[x if hasattr(x, '__iter__') else [x] for x in L if x is not None])))
```

I'm told this may not work in Python 3 because of how `str` is implemented there. Anyway I'm only posting these ideas so that you are aware of functionality already available in the Python standard library under `itertools`. Have fun learning Python!

Comment: I think this will blow up if there's a non-None element at the top level (that is, if you have `[None, <Car object at ...>, [None, None]]` or similar. I don't know if that's a plausible situation for the questioner, but it could be.

Comment: Ahh yes, you're right. But I'm also not sure if that's plausible for the OP. My assumption was that `None` appears at the top level because there's no `list`, otherwise there's a `list` that may contain `None` or `Car` objects. I basically posted to point out `itertools` functionality, and the other SO post.