# Python - "Joining" list of lists of different types

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, join, list-comprehension

So I have a `list of lists` like this:

```
my_list = [['hi','Ohio',[1,0.0]],['bye','NewYork',[2,0.0]],['go','Maine',[3,0.0]]]
```

As you can see, it has 3 different types (`string`, `ints` and `floats`).

And I need to 'join' the sublists together to output a new list with the form:

```
>>> new_list

[['hiOhio10.0'], ['byeNewYork20.0'], ['goMaine30.0']]
```

So to do that, I've tried doing the following 'list comprehension':

```
>>> new_list = [["".join(["".join(str(a)) for a in b])] for b in mylist]
```

But that gave me the output:

```
>>> new_list

[['hiOhio[1, 0.0]'], ['byeNewYork[2, 0.0]'], ['goMaine[3, 0.0]']]
```

Which is not quite what I was after.

Other things I've tried:

1. Adding another for-loop in the previously shown list comprehension.

   For example:

   ```
   [[["".join(["".join(str(c)) for c in a])]for a in b] for b in my_list]
   ```

   But that gave me this error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#88>", line 1, in <module>
       [[["".join(["".join(str(c)) for c in a])]for a in b] for b in my_list]
   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
   ```
2. I've also tried following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) on 'list flattening', but it seems like that would expand *every* entry in my list which I don't want

Any help and/or tips would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why be complex when you can simply do it with for loop

```
     new_list=[''.join(str(y)  for x in z for y in x) for z in my_list]
```

Comment: This is actually what I was trying to do from the beginning! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this list-comprehension

```
>>> [[''.join(i[:2])+''.join(map(str,my_list[0][2]))] for i in my_list]
[['hiOhio10.0'], ['byeNewYork10.0'], ['goMaine10.0']]
```

Assumption - The sublists are always as mentioned

Docs for - [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: Note - `map` is slower than a list comprehension whenever there is use of `lambda` functions. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

Comment: @logic Anytime! All the best in future!

Answer (score 3):

A bit more readable and less error-prone:

```
def concat(item):
    if type(item) is list:
        return ''.join([concat(i) for i in item])
    # else:
    return str(item)

[concat(item) for item in my_list]
```

Comment: More readable beats conciseness any time, you got my plus one :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map` to run a `lambda` that flattens each item and `join`s them, after it `join`s the elements of each third item in each list:

```
map(lambda x: ["".join([x[0], x[1], "".join(map(str, x[2]))])], my_list)
```

**Result**

```
[['hiOhio10.0'], ['byeNewYork20.0'], ['goMaine30.0']]
```

Comment: I like this because it solves exactly the problem given without getting overly generic.  However, I think map + lambda is more clearly expressed as a list comprehension: `["".join([x[0], x[1], "".join(map(str, x[2]))]) for x in my_list]`.  The comprehension is shorter and should be more efficient.  (But of course this then turns your answer into @BhargavRao's.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski You're right, I actually like your (and BhargavRao's) suggestion better than my answer. Any Map+lambda could be interpreted into a list comprehension - and that's a more pythonic way to do things (as well as more efficient according to what I read as well).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function to flatten arbitrarily nested iterables you can do:

```
[''.join(map(str, flatten(sublist))) for sublist in my_list]
```

---

Here's the `flatten` I used (adapted from [How can I flatten lists without splitting strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5286571/1322401):

```
def flatten(it):
    for item in it:
        if hasattr(item, '__iter__') and not isinstance(item, basestring):
            for subitem in flatten(item):
                yield subitem
        else:
            yield item
```

There are other good ways to flatten in [flattening a shallow list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python).  These mostly don't add a special case for strings, but that may not matter.