# How to convert sublist to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am having the list like this below,

```
[
    'August 28, 2017',
    'gilbert arizona',
    '33.3528264',
    '-111.789027',
    '1236 Feet',
    "[u'  ASCE 7* Ground Snow LoadElevation 2,000 feet', u' Ground Snow Load is0 psf']"
]
```

I want convert this to the form

```
[
    'August 28, 2017',
    'gilbert arizona',
    '33.3528264',
    '-111.789027',
    '1236 Feet',
    'ASCE 7* Ground Snow LoadElevation 2,000 feet',
    ' Ground Snow Load is0 psf'
]
```

Comment: Lookup: XY Problem. You don't have a sublist, you have a string, which is a `str(list_object)`. Please add your actual code that generated this

Comment: You could run `eval` but that's not secure.

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I flatten lists without splitting strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286541/how-can-i-flatten-lists-without-splitting-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with cricket_007, you really should address this at the source, as it's poorly formed data and any solution will be brittle and prone to breaking. That said, if you just need something quick-and-dirty, the following should do the trick while avoiding using the unsafe `eval` function.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def flatten(iterable):
    result = []

    for item in iterable:
        try:
            item_eval = literal_eval(item)
            if not isinstance(item_eval, list):
                raise ValueError()
        except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
            result.append(item)
        else:
            result.extend(flatten(item_eval))

    return result


>>> data = [
...     'August 28, 2017',
...     'gilbert arizona',
...     '33.3528264',
...     '-111.789027',
...     '1236 Feet',
...     "[u'  ASCE 7* Ground Snow LoadElevation 2,000 feet', u' Ground Snow Load is0 psf']"
... ]

>>> flatten(data)
['August 28, 2017', 'gilbert arizona', '33.3528264', '-111.789027', '1236 Feet', u'  ASCE 7* Ground Snow LoadElevation 2,000 feet', u' Ground Snow Load is0 psf']
```

Comment: How to remove the u' from the flatten(data). Please help me

Comment: The `u` just denotes that it's a unicode string. You don't need to get rid of it. if you print the list element it won't be included.

Comment: result.append(str(item)) try this u' will be removed instead of result.append(item)

Comment: The `u` will show up if you print the whole list, but not if you just print an individual element. As I said, it's just telling you that the string is `unicode`. The `u` isn't actually part of the data, you don't need to worry about it.