# Joining two RDDs with multiple value components and flattening the result

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have 2 RDDs with the same key, but different value types (more than 2 values). I want to join these RDDs by key, and append their values next in the final tuple (see below). What's the best way to do this?

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([ (1, "test1", [5,6,7]), (2, "test2", [1,2,3]) ])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([ (1, "Foo"), (2, "Bar") ])
```

**Desired Output RDD**

```
[ (1, "Foo", "test1", [5,6,7]), (2, "Bar", "test2", [1,2,3]) ]
```

---

Doing a direct join does not work:

```
print(rdd2.join(rdd1).collect())
#[(1, ('Foo', 'test1')), (2, ('Bar', 'test2'))]
```

This ignores the the rest of the values in `rdd1` and the output is in the wrong format.

Comment: Why mention left outer join?

Comment: Please, update your question because Left outer join does not retrieve the final RDD of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use `join` here, granted that you first map the `rdds` into the form `(key, value)`.

```python
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([ (1, "test1", [5,6,7]), (2, "test2", [1,2,3]) ])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([ (1, "Foo"), (2, "Bar") ])

def map_to_kvp(row):
    if len(row) < 3:
        return row
    return (row[0], tuple(row[1:]))

rdd3 = rdd2.map(map_to_kvp).join(rdd1.map(map_to_kvp))
print(rdd3.collect())
#[
#    (1, ('Foo', ('test1', [5, 6, 7]))), 
#    (2, ('Bar', ('test2', [1, 2, 3])))
#]
```

Now you've got all of the data in the right places, but you just need to flatten the resulting rows.

In this case you'll have to write your own `flatten` function to avoid flattening the `string` and `list` as well.

We can build upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5286571/5858851) to [How can I flatten lists without splitting strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5286541/5858851) to make your own function:

```python
def flatten(foo):
    for x in foo:
        if hasattr(x, '__iter__') and not isinstance(x, str) and not isinstance(x, list):
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x

rdd4 = rdd3.map(lambda row: tuple(flatten(row)))
print(rdd4.collect())
#[(1, 'Foo', 'test1', [5, 6, 7]), (2, 'Bar', 'test2', [1, 2, 3])]
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought join could be done on a tuple with more than 1 value, but one must group all values into one tuple...