# Flattening list in python without flatten the individual strings in the list

Tags: python, list

This is the list i am trying to flatten.

```
pp=['a1b0c00',['00ffbcd','c2df']]
flat_list = [item for sublist in pp for item in sublist]
flat_list: ['a', '1', 'b', '0', 'c', '0', '0', '00ffbcd', 'c2df']
```

Expected result is a single list:`['a1b0c00','00ffbcd','c2df']`  .

How to flatten this kind of lists in python?

Comment: @jpp: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286541/how-can-i-flatten-lists-without-splitting-strings) is a more relevant dupe related to strings

Comment: @Bazingaa, Thanks, added to the list.

Answer (score 4):

This is one approach.

```
pp=['a1b0c00',['00ffbcd','c2df']]
res = []
for i in pp:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        res.extend(i)
    else:
        res.append(i)
print( res )
```

**Output:**

```
['a1b0c00', '00ffbcd', 'c2df']
```