# Flatten a list of floats and numpy arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, flatten

I have the following `list` instance:

```
import numpy as np
l = [4.0, 0.0, np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0]), np.array([2.0, 4.0, 0.0])]
```

Is it too much trouble to get a single list of the following values:

```
[4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 0.0]
```

i.e. a flattened list.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: It's no different to flattening a nested list. What is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I flatten lists without splitting strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286541/how-can-i-flatten-lists-without-splitting-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `np.hstack(l)`, which horizontally stacks 1D arrays, lists (iterables), and scalars. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ndarray.tolist()` to convert the arrays to list objects, and then adding them to the list, for example:

```
a1 = np.array([0,1,2,3])
l1 = [-2,-1]

a1_list = a1.tolist()
l1.extend(a1_list)
```

Will return a flattened list from -2 to 3. That is in case you want to have the elements in a list object, but the arrays object is in most cases preferred to work with numbers.